# How to specify the width of site column in a list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I have developed a list in SharePoint. While entering new item in it, like name, if I keep on typing  it gets spread over a line making the width of cloumn spread over page. I want to limit the width of site column so as the column's value spreads over multiple lines instead of spreading over one. How can I do this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a setting you can configure in SharePoint. You will need to write some custom code using css and possibly javascript that will set the width of the column. You can make a change like this in [SharePoint Designer](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/related-technologies/pages/sharepoint-designer.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You must use min-width (CSS) in your block.

Comment: I am not using any CSS code. I was wondering if it could be done through SharePoint alone.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom XSLT for this. There you have loop all the column and need to specify the `overflow:auto`, `hidden`,.. CSS property. So it automatically get effect based on your internal name of the field.

So whereever you have the field it automatically get affected. If it for one single view you can use JavaScript to achieve this but this is not right way to do.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are entering can be displayed in many ways. Today in a table format, tomorrow in a dropdown etc. You should distinguish between:

- limiting the amount of data that can be entered in a site column (can be done in SharePoint alone, when you design your list)
- limiting the wrapping of the words in a table cell today or trimming the values in a dropdown tomorrow (can be done using HTML/CSS "nowrap" if you display the list values in a browser app, or differently if you show the values in a WinForms app)